# StringBuffer array fails where String works

Tags: java, string, exception, stringbuffer

I am trying to understand the underlying difference between initializing Strings and StringBuffer
The following code works fine. (al is an `ArrayList<String>`)

```
String[] sa = new String[al.size()];
System.arraycopy(al.toArray(), 0, sa, 0, al.size());
```

However when i use StringBuffer array it wont work.

```
StringBuffer[] sa = new StringBuffer[al.size()];
System.arraycopy(al.toArray(), 0, sa, 0, al.size());
```

It gives me following exception

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at practice.ArrayListDemo.main(ArrayListDemo.java:34)
```

Can someone help me understand the logic/reason? It is not clear how string being immutable makes a difference.

Comment: Immutability has nothing to do with it. You're trying to mix array types.

Answer (score 3):

How did you define al? Is it with the right type - `StringBuffer`? When I did the following there was no problem:

```
    List<StringBuffer> al = new ArrayList<StringBuffer>();
    StringBuffer[] sa = new StringBuffer[al.size()];
    System.arraycopy(al.toArray(), 0, sa, 0, al.size());
```

Comment: no, i made a mistake. my arraylist was initialised with String.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've declared `al` as an `ArrayList<String>`, we can safely assume that you've stored `String` objects in it.

But here

```
StringBuffer[] sa = new StringBuffer[al.size()];
System.arraycopy(al.toArray(), 0, sa, 0, al.size());
```

you're trying to copy `String` elements in a `StringBuffer` array. That doesn't work since `String` is not a subtype of `StringBuffer`.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. i just understood the exception is thrown by the arraycopy method for type mismatch.

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that provides the actual reasoning behind the solution.